# Proof About Division of Integers

Tags: proof-verification

Here is a problem I just finished working on:

> Prove that if $n$ is composite then there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $n$ divides $ab$ but not $n$ does not divide either $a$ or $b$.

One thing I noticed while proving this is, that we are showing that there **exist** a pair of integers such that the conditional relationship is true; is it possible to find a pair such that it is not true, that $n$ divides both $a$ and $b$ individually?

Comment: Yes there is! The simplest example is that for any $n$, $n\mid n\times n$.

Comment: Hint: $\ n = ab\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid ab\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

The words "there are" tell you that the problem is asking about existence.

Words that mean **existence** ($\exists$) include "there is", "there exists", "one can find", etc.

Words that mean the statement is true **for all** ($\forall$) members of the specified set include "all", "every", etc.

"Any" is a tricky word that is best avoided.

EDIT: For a specific answer to your specific question, the statement is not true for all integers. Let $n = a = b = 4$. Then $n$ is composite and it divides $a$ and $b$ and $ab$.

Comment: That is what I figured, that the problem was concerned with existence, but I was not exactly certain.

Answer (score -1):

$60 = 15\times 4$.  So $60$ divides $15\times4$ but $60$ does not divide $15$ and $60$ does not divide $4$.

You can do the same with any composite number.